# light view matrix in stable cascaded shadow mapping

Tags: c++, math, opengl, glm-math, shadow-mapping

I have recently implemented cascaded shadow maps and make it stable by following this [post](https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/591684-xna-40---shimmering-shadow-maps/). Now everything works, except that when I move directional light to the top mid of the world, the shadow suddenly turns all dark. With some debugging I find that the light view matrix is causing the problem.

This is how I compute the view matrix:

```cpp
glm::mat4 view = glm::lookAt(
    center + lightDirNorm * nearOffset,
    center,
    camera.worldUP
);
```

`center` is the bounding sphere center, `worldUP` is a constant value of `vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)`, `lightDirNorm` is the normalized light direction from world origin to light position.

When I move light position to `vec3(0.0, 20.0, 0.0)`, `lightDirNorm` becomes `vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)`. In this case, view direction is in the same line as `worldUP` vector. As a result, it is not possible to do cross product and compute the `right` vector. This is bothering because it is a common light direction.

Because the shadow is stable, the `worldUP` vector used here has to be something constant. The only workaround I could think of is to add a small offset to the `worldUP` vector, to make it like `vec3(0.00001, 1.0, 0.0)`.

I'm wondering if there are better ways to handle that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Making it stable" is not applicable to a light source whose direction changes. The stability refers to the camera movement while the light source is stationary. Consequently you can choose any orthogonal `up` vector as a function of the `lightDirNorm`, and it will keep your shadows stable.

I'd also suggest [staying away from any `lookAt` functions](https://stannum.io/blog/0UaG8R). Instead specify your light direction by azimuth and altitude, and use rotation matrices to calculate the view matrix without any danger of singularities.